# Why is my date conversion so off?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I run these two statements in sql and the dates are two days apart. This ruins my query. Why are they not both 10/13/2015?

```
select sysdate from dual
-- 10/13/2015 5:09:43 PM

select trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') from dual
-- 10/11/2015
```

Comment: Do you just want the date and not the time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[trunc 'DAY'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) returns the starting day of the week. Use `'DDD'`, `'DD'` or `'J'` to truncate to a day.

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me wacky

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to truncate the time. So you can just remove the second parameter if you want to truncate the time to midnight.

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;
/
SELECT to_char(trunc(SYSDATE),'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS')
---------------------------------------
10/14/2015 07:35:24      

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS')
----------------------------------------------
10/14/2015 00:00:00
```